# How in magento importing more rows then found

Tags: php, magento, csv, import

When they importing a .CSV file Magento imports also the old .CSV files with it.

There is only one file in var/import folder lets say with 2 rows. When we start import its shows found 2 records importing 1 of 200 (this 200 is random number) and then old data is rewriten with the old .CSV file.

But this file we have imported some days ago and the new file have 2 rows. Somehow somewhere there is a chach or some memory that still appends with the import.

One time I delete the import table in the database and some time it was working properly but after 2 weeks again the same problem.

Can someone put me on the right direction please? where to search the problem.

Comment: What are you importing? products or some custom data?

Comment: import products, but .csv file have only 2 rows, but then found 200 rows. Is the old CSV file. I don't understand why this happens

Answer (score 2):

In MySQL, clean your table "dataflow_batch_import" and it will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Datas I had already imported (on local server) were mixed to new import datas (online).

Simply truncate table "dataflow_batch_import" and it will solve the problem.

Hope it helps.